# Flash ExternalInterface crashes under Firefox

Tags: flash, firefox, firefox-addon, externalinterface

After a while i got down to my project using Flash and its ExternalInterface.
What I found after running the used-to-work html site embedding flash and JavaScript was that it stopped working. I ran ExternalInterface example from asdoc with the same result - sendToActionscript is not a function.
After several hours i came up with the solution - It was caused by FF add-one FlashFirebug (3.4.2) after removing the plugin it started working as expected.
I hope that this post may save you a few hours of frustration.
Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

FlashFirebug 3.5.2 should solve this issue. Give it a shot.